# Jamine unit test error for @select ng-redux

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, mocking, redux

My component.ts file looks like below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { select } from 'ng2-redux';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PersonalDetailsComponent } from '../personal-details/personal-details.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-details',
  templateUrl: './profile-details.component.html'
})
export class ProfileDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @select(['customerData', 'personalDetails'])personalDetails:Observable<object>; //<------if i comment out @select statement, then the tests work 
  @select(['loading']) loading: Observable<boolean>;//<------if i comment out @select statement, then the tests work 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

And my jasmine test looks like this

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux';
import { ProfileDetailsComponent } from './profile-details.component';
import { customerData } from '../data/customerProfileDataMock';
import { PersonalDetailsComponent } from '../personal-details/personal-details.component'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

class RouterStub { navigate(params) { } }
class MockSelect { }
class MockObservable<T> {}
class NgReduxStub {
  constructor() { }
  dispatch = () => undefined;
  getState = () => { return customerData; };
  subscribe = () => undefined;
}

describe('ProfileDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ProfileDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProfileDetailsComponent, PersonalDetailsComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub },
        { provide: select, useClass: MockSelect },
        { provide: NgRedux, useClass: NgReduxStub },
        { provide: Observable, useClass: MockObservable }
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the profile details page', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Not sure whats missing, but the @select statement is not getting mocked and getting the below error when i run the tests using command 'ng test'

```
TypeError: ng_redux_1.NgRedux.instance is undefined in src/test.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the same package as I am, but I note that ng2-redux on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-redux) links through to the github repository https://github.com/angular-redux/store, so perhaps there's been some merging of branches.

If so, I'd suggest an update to you package. They have recently added MockNgRedux which you can add to your test with

```
import { NgReduxTestingModule, MockNgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store/testing';
```

This is added into TestBed with

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      NgReduxTestingModule,
    ],
```

and can be used to test components which use `@select()` by setting up values on particular selectors with

```
const stub = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub(selector);
stub.next(values);
stub.complete();
```

Note that methods are static and don't require an instance of MockNgRedux.

Be sure to clear down the mock store between tests

```
beforeEach(() => {
  MockNgRedux.reset();
});
```